# Updating railities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need some help updating my Rails to the correct version. I do not know how to go about doing so. When I "bundle install --without production," I get the following error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.8) ruby depends on
      actionpack (= 4.1.8) ruby

    jquery-rails (= 4.0.0.beta2) ruby depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 4.2.0.beta) ruby depends on
        actionpack (4.2.0.beta1)
```

I have the following in my Gemfile:
source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.0.beta2'
gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'rails-html-sanitizer', '1.0.1'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I am running Rails 4.1.8 with Ruby ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]

Comment: The combination of gems you have specified (in particular rails 4.1.8 and jquery-rails 4.0.0beta2) is invalid. If I were you I'd remove the constraint on jquery-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that rails and jquery-rails depend on different verions of actionpack.

Try setting your jquery-rails gem to an older version using the greater than or equal to sign like this:

```
gem 'jquery-rails',         '>= 3.0.0'
```

That will allow bundler some flexibility in selecting a version that does not have conflicting dependencies.

Comment: The latest you can use sans the "railties beta" is currently jquery-rails ~> 3.1.2.  The problem is, this leaves you stuck with a version of jquery from Sep 2, 2014 (with a bug / conflict I hoped to get rid of).